# Error in auto.arima with seasonal dummy variables

Tags: r, regression, arima, seasonality, error-message

I have a monthly data set for 15 years. I tried to apply SARIMA model on it. However, thanks to the comments here, I realized that it has deterministic seasonality. So I add seasonal dummy variables (11 variables) to the linear regression analysis. I saw that all of the seasonal dummy variables are significant. Then, I tried to use `auto.arima` function with `xreg`. However, I got the following error:

```r
ts<- ts(data$col1,start=2007,frequency = 12)

Call:
tslm(formula = ts~ season(ts))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3733 -1.0393  0.0929  1.2136  3.7267 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             0.3733     0.4939   0.756  0.45081    
season(ts)February    2.2000     0.6985   3.150  0.00194 ** 
season(ts)March       6.4667     0.6985   9.258  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)April      11.1267     0.6985  15.930  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)May        16.2067     0.6985  23.202  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)June       20.5533     0.6985  29.425  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)July       24.4200     0.6985  34.961  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)August     24.2195     0.7109  34.071  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)September  19.9338     0.7109  28.042  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)October    13.4052     0.7109  18.858  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)November    6.5981     0.7109   9.282  < 2e-16 ***
season(ts)December    1.8410     0.7109   2.590  0.01047 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.913 on 163 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9548,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9517 
F-statistic: 312.8 on 11 and 163 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**Residuals of the linear model**

[image: residuals]

```r
library(forecast)
sereg <- cbind(date=model.matrix(~as.factor(rep(1:12))))
sreg <- sereg[, -1]
colnames(sreg) <- c("February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

auto.arima(ts, xreg = sreg)
```

When I wanted to use `auto.arima`, I got the following error:

```r
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ xregg, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'xregg')
```

I think I am missing something, maybe something fundamental. Do you have any idea?

Comment: How many rows does `sreg` have? How long is `ts`?

Comment: @ChrisHaug sreg has 12 row and ts has 175 observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sreg` matrix has only 12 rows, yet your data has 175 observations. The number of rows of `sreg` should be the same as the number of rows of data.

In any case, you can use the `seasonaldummy()` function to make your life easier:

```r
library(forecast)
ts <- ts(rnorm(175), start=2007, frequency=12)
fit <- auto.arima(ts, xreg=seasonaldummy(ts))
fit
#> Series: ts 
#> Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,1)[12] errors 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          sma1  intercept     Jan     Feb     Mar      Apr     May     Jun
#>       -0.2756    -0.3466  0.4246  0.2312  0.2700  -0.2165  0.1581  0.1670
#> s.e.   0.1163     0.1754  0.2431  0.2431  0.2439   0.2449  0.2437  0.2431
#>          Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov
#>       0.1037  0.1136  0.1500  0.6898  0.4680
#> s.e.  0.2428  0.2484  0.2474  0.2472  0.2477
#> 
#> sigma^2 = 0.8316:  log likelihood = -225.9
#> AIC=479.8   AICc=482.43   BIC=524.11
forecast(fit, xreg=seasonaldummy(ts, h=6))
#>          Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
#> Aug 2021     0.08994815 -1.0787477 1.2586440 -1.697418 1.877314
#> Sep 2021    -0.37081145 -1.5395073 0.7978844 -2.158177 1.416555
#> Oct 2021     0.19511293 -0.9735829 1.3638087 -1.592253 1.982479
#> Nov 2021     0.15150420 -1.0171916 1.3202000 -1.635862 1.938870
#> Dec 2021    -0.43133856 -1.6000344 0.7373573 -2.218705 1.356027
#> Jan 2022     0.08201154 -1.0866843 1.2507074 -1.705354 1.869378
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>